# PETAPOCO - Invalid object name

Tags: common-table-expression, petapoco

I am using CTE with PetaPOCO and getting a strange error
`SQL Exception: Invalid Object Name PayTransactionForRollingVacationAverage` that references the model that the data should map to.

The code is as follows.

```
public IEnumerable<PayTransactionForRollingVacationAverage> GetPayTransactionForRollingVacationAverage(DateTime payEndingDate)
    {
        PointsNorth.PetaPoco.Sql sql = new PointsNorth.PetaPoco.Sql();
        sql.Append(@"
            ;with HolidayWeeks as
            (
                Select Distinct EmployeeId, PayEndDate, 'Y' as HolidayWeek
                  from PayTransactions
                 where PayEndDate = @payEndingDate
                   and LaborCode in ('251', '249')
            )", new { payEndingDate });

        sql.Append(@"
            Select 
                PT.EmployeeId, 
                PT.PayEndDate, 
                J.JobClass, 
                PayCodes.AverageRateCode,
                PT.RegularHours, 
                PT.RegularRate, 
                PT.RegularAmount                    
              from PayTransactions PT
                Left Outer Join PayCodes on PayCodes.PayCodeCode = PT.LaborCode
                Left Outer Join HolidayWeeks as H on H.PayEndDate = PT.PayEndDate and H.EmployeeId = PT.EmployeeId
                Inner Join Jobs as J on J.JobId = PT.JobId
            where PT.PayEndDate = @payEndingDate 
              and IsNull(H.HolidayWeek, 'N') <> 'Y'
            order by PT.EmployeeId, PT.PayEndDate, J.JobClass", new { payEndingDate });

        var data = Database.Query<PayTransactionForRollingVacationAverage>(sql);

        return data;
    }
```

The model is pretty simple:

```
public class PayTransactionForRollingVacationAverage
    {
        public long EmployeeId { get; set; } 
        public DateTime PayEndDate { get; set; } 
        public string JobClass { get; set; }
        public string AverageRateCode { get; set; }
        public decimal RegularHours { get; set; } 
        public decimal RegularRate { get; set; } 
        public decimal RegularAmount { get; set; }         
    }
```

I tried breaking the SQL up to make sure it was building correctly, but I still get the error.  Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: SQL looks ok - you are on SQL Server right?

Comment: Can you accept my answer? It's helped me twice.

Answer (score 16):

Remove the whitespace before the semi-colon.

According to Alex Jorgenson's link, this is fixed if you make a semi-colon the very first character.
According to my testing, this is strictly the first character, i.e. if there is even some whitespace before the semi-colon, the auto-generated code will still be spit out.

Comment: Haha! I just had the same problem again, 9 months later and found this, which was the solution. Good job, me!

Comment: 4 years later and I have found myself back to this post. I love SO!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Peta Poco. It appears to be fixed in some version but I don't know which one. You can find more information and a work around for this particular issue at https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/issues/22